# Gradle Scala plugin cannot find ScalaObject

Tags: scala, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have the following [Gradle-based Scala project](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/scala-examples) on GitHub.

If you clone it and run `./gradlew run` you'll get the following exception:

```
:shared:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:shared:compileScala
missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'package.class'.
Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scala.
one error found
:shared:compileScala FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:compileScala'.
> Compilation failed

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The only comparable stack traces I've been able to find from the Google Gods have all involved SBT and Scala projects, *not* Gradle and Scala.

**Can anybody figure out what's going on here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have got some dependencies conflicts. I've seen that your are using different Scala versions in your subprojects. This might cause some binary incompatibility issues between your Scala versions and the libraries that.

For instance, you are using `'net.liftweb:lift-json_2.9.1:2.6.3'`, which is binary compatible with `Scala 2.9.1`, but you have `Scala 2.12.1` and `Scala 2.11.8`. This might be a potential problem candidate.

If I were you, I would go through all the list of dependencies and check the right version that the project requires.

You can use:
`gradle dependencies`
`gradle dependencyInsight <dependency-name>`

to get more information about how your dependencies resolve.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much (+1), that was it! I changed all my subprojects to use the same Scala version and I replaced Lift JSON with the latest GSON artifact, and the problems went away. Thanks again!